# Similar time submissions for tests

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe for each of my online students shaped like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Class","Student","Challenge","Time"])
```

I create a temporary df for each of the challenges like this:

```
for ch in challenges:
    df=main_df.loc[(df['Challenge'] == ch)]
```

I want to group the records that are 5 minutes apart from each other. The idea is that I will create a df that shows a group of students working together and answering the questions relatively the same time. I have different aspects of catching cheaters but I need to be able to show that two or more students have been answering the questions relatively the same time.

I was thinking of using resampling or using a grouper method but I'm a bit confused on how to implement it. Could someone guide me to the right direction for solving for this?

Sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Class": ["A"] * 4 + ["B"] * 2,
        "Student": ['Scooby','Daphne','Shaggy','Fred','Velma','Scrappy'],
        "Challenge": ["Challenge3"] *6,
        "Time": ['07/10/2022 08:22:44','07/10/2022 08:27:22','07/10/2022 08:27:44','07/10/2022 08:29:55','07/10/2022 08:33:14','07/10/2022 08:48:44'],
    }   
)
```

EDIT:

For the output I was thinking of having another df with an extra column called 'Grouping' and have an incremental number for the groups that were discovered.
The final df would first be empty and then appended or concated with the grouping df.

```
new_df = pd.dataframe(columns=['Class','Student','Challenge','Time','Grouping'])

new_df = pd.concat([new_df,df])

  Class  Student   Challenge                 Time  Grouping
1     A   Daphne  Challenge3  07/10/2022 08:27:22         1
2     A   Shaggy  Challenge3  07/10/2022 08:27:44         1
3     A     Fred  Challenge3  07/10/2022 08:29:55         1
```

The purpose of this is so that I may have multiple samples to verify if the same two or more students are sharing answers.

EDIT 2:

I was thinking that I could do a lambda based operation. What if I created another column called "Threshold_Delta" that calculates the difference in time from one answer to another? Then I need to figure out how to group those minutes up.

```
df['Challenge_Delta'] = (df['Time']-df['Time'].shift())
```

Comment: Could you supply a small sample of one of those data frames and some desired output?

Comment: Sure. One sec....

Comment: Generally you could do 5-minute groups with something starting with `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="time", freq="5T"))...`.  But that would not group students within 5 minutes that were on either side of the 5-minute boundary.

Comment: darn..that is what I need tho.

Comment: I added the sample df.

Comment: technically I would need the freq="2.5T" but grouping the students within 2.5 minutes on either side of the 2.5 minute boundary is the goal.

Comment: can you post expected output please

Comment: Fo each row, do you want the index of rows that are +-2.5mins from it?That means for row 0 we will have index1,2 for row 1 you will have row 0, 2,3

Comment: I see a  Scooby-Daphne-Shaggy group and a Daphne-Shaggy-Fred-Velma group.  How do want this output represented?

Comment: I was thinking of the output being another df with an extra column called 'Grouping' and have an incremental number for the groups that were discovered.

Comment: I edited my post with a possible output.

Comment: The purpose of this is so that I may have multiple samples to verify if the same two or more students are sharing answers.

Comment: I don't understand how the expected table was created

Comment: I added that detail in my post for your convenience. The findings are to be concated to an empty df.

Comment: Looks like Velma not in the example output probably since she is in a different class.

Comment: Well, it should look at other classes because they are sister classes..I was thinking of the grouping to center the time amongst the records not each student...or is that not possible? Maybe if not then the 'Grouping' column would be a list that can be appended.

Comment: What do you folks think?

Comment: what do you mean filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution implements a rolling time list.  The logic is this – keep adding entries as long as all the entries in the list are within the time window.  When you detect that some of the entries are not in the time window relative to the most current (to be added) entry then that indicates that you have a unique cheater (maybe) group.  Then write out that group as a list, remove the out-of-window entries and add the newest entry.  At the end there may a set of entries left on the list. `dump_last()` allows that set to be pulled.  After you have these lists then there is a whole bunch of cheater-detecting analytics that you could perform.

**Make sure the `Time` column is `datetime`**

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

**The Rolling Time List Class defintion**

```
class RollingTimeList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Student','Time'])
        self.window = pd.Timedelta('5T')

    def __add(self, row):
        idx = self.cur.index.max()
        new_idx = idx+1 if idx==idx else 0
        self.cur.loc[new_idx] = row[['Student','Time']]

    def handle_row(self, row):
        rc = None

        if len(self.cur) > 0:
            window_mask = (row['Time'] - self.cur['Time']).abs() <= self.window

            if ~window_mask.all():
                if len(self.cur) > 1:
                    rc = self.cur['Student'].to_list()
                self.cur = self.cur.loc[window_mask]

        self.__add(row)

        return rc

    def dump_last(self):
        rc = None

        if len(self.cur) > 1:
            rc = self.cur['Student'].to_list()

        self.cur = self.cur[0:0]
        return rc
```

**Instantiate and apply the class**

```
rolling_list = RollingTimeList()

s = df.apply(rolling_list.handle_row, axis=1)

idx = s.index.max()
s.loc[idx+1 if idx==idx else 0] = rolling_list.dump_last()

print(s.dropna())
```

**Result**

```
3    [Scooby, Daphne, Shaggy]
4      [Daphne, Shaggy, Fred]
5               [Fred, Velma]
```

**Merge that back into the original data frame**

```
df['window_groups'] = s
df['window_groups'] = df['window_groups'].shift(-1).fillna('')

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
  Class  Student   Challenge                Time             window_groups
0     A   Scooby  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:22:44
1     A   Daphne  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:27:22
2     A   Shaggy  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:27:44  [Scooby, Daphne, Shaggy]
3     A     Fred  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:29:55    [Daphne, Shaggy, Fred]
4     B    Velma  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:33:14             [Fred, Velma]
5     B  Scrappy  Challenge3 2022-07-10 08:48:44
```

**Visualization idea: cross reference table**

```
dfd = pd.get_dummies(s.dropna().apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
xrf = dfd.T.dot(dfd)
print(xrf)
```

**Result**

```
        Daphne  Fred  Scooby  Shaggy  Velma
Daphne       2     1       1       2      0
Fred         1     2       0       1      1
Scooby       1     0       1       1      0
Shaggy       2     1       1       2      0
Velma        0     1       0       0      1
```

**Or as Series of unique student combinations and counts**

```
combos = xrf.stack()
unique_combo_mask = combos.index.get_level_values(0)<combos.index.get_level_values(1)
print(combos[unique_combo_mask])
```

**Result**

```
Daphne  Fred      1
        Scooby    1
        Shaggy    2
        Velma     0
Fred    Scooby    0
        Shaggy    1
        Velma     1
Scooby  Shaggy    1
        Velma     0
Shaggy  Velma     0
```

Also from here, you could determine that within some kind of time constraint (or other constraint) that the count really should be not more than one - due to overlapping lists.  Like in this example, Daphne and Shaggy probably should not be counted twice.  They didn't really come within 5 minutes of each other on two separate occasions. In which case anything greater than one could be set to one before being accumulated into a larger pool.

Comment: THIS looks awesome! I will test this out on my side. I did not even think about it being a rolling list, although I did wonder if I had to iterate every record through every record. If this works then I will accept your answer. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Hey - I added some post-processing ideas to the end of the answer.  I updated about the same time you made your last comment.  Wanted to make sure you saw those.